# (wired) network down after a while with 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

I'm running 16.04 since a few days, and I'm noticing something: after some time (hours or days - I quite never shut down this computer), the network connection stops working. I can't connect to anything with a browser, the ftp server stops answering to requests (local network), no network.
The network icon shows nothing wrong, if I click twice on "Activate network" (so it goes to unactivated state, then back to normal) network connection is working again.
Is that a known issue ? Does anyone has an idea where to look for useful info I could post here (I don't know what log could be really related).
Thanks in advance for your answsers

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple shell script to round this problem (bug,etc ) that it will be like this :

`/bin/bash
ping google.com 
if [ $?=0 ] 
then
else 
systemctl restart NetworkManager #or ifup eth0 
fi` 
And put this script on crontab.