# Intermittent lost in network connectivity (log files?)

Tags: networking, 16.04, wired

Perhaps this is unrelated to the latest upgrade to 16.04, but since upgrading, my computer has been inexplicably losing network connectivity (cabled network, not wireless).  So, if I boot up, it works and it'll continue to for days (it's acting like a server, so it isn't normally turned off) but will suddenly lose its network connection.

I've found similar problems from older versions of Ubuntu and the cause seemed to be bugs in the kernels.  I guess that's possible since 15.10 was never a problem for me.

It would be great if I could solve this problem.  But I'm interested in suggestions of log files that I should look at or perhaps I can increase the verbosity of log files to get a better idea of what's wrong.  I can't find out which files in /var/log/ I should be looking at...

PS:  Found at least one other person with this problem ([(wired) network down after a while with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763031/wired-network-down-after-a-while-with-16-04)).

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?  We're having the same problem with a server where we made a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The problem "disappeared" after an update of the kernel a few weeks after I posted that message.  And since then, the problem hasn't reappeared.  The computer is now on 16.10, though.  That shouldn't be the reason since other computers I work with are using 16.04 and do not have network problems.  Perhaps it's a combination of the server make and 16.04?!?

Comment: Of course, you should try to rule out other problems like the network cable, the switch, etc.  Any of them can also cause problems with loss in network.  Should try swapping them out before blaming Ubuntu...